# SQL Server: change first day of week to Sunday using DATEPART with ISOWK parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to get **week numbers** for some set of dates. For example, for Jan  2016 it should be something like:

```
[Week Number]
53             <--- for dates from Jan 1 to Jan 2
1              <--- for dates from Jan 3 to Jan 9
2              <--- for dates from Jan 10 to Jan 16
...            <--- etc.
```

As you see, week should start from Sunday. I've used following function to set start day:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
```

And this one to get week number:

```
DATEPART(ISOWK, SOME_DATE)
```

But I've noticed that `DATEFIRST` doesn't affect results when `ISOWK` being used - week always starts from Monday.

So, what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**UPD:**

I've made a function, seems it works good:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWeekNumber]
( 
    @date as DATETIME,
    @offset as INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @weekNumber as int
        DECLARE @year as int

        SET @date = DATEADD(MINUTE, @offset, @date)
        SET @year = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date), CAST(@date AS DATE)))

        IF @@DATEFIRST = 7 
            BEGIN
                SET @date = DATEADD(day, 1, @date)
            END
        SET @weekNumber = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date)
        RETURN concat(@year, ', Week ', right('0' + convert(nvarchar, @weekNumber), 2))
    END
```

You need to pass the date and timezone offset (in minutes). And `SET DATEFIRST @startDay` before executing this function (1 - Monday, 7 - Sunday). Example:

```
DECLARE @date as DATETIME
SET @date = '2016-01-03 12:00'

SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT dbo.GetWeekNumber(@date, 0) -- 2015, Week 53

SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT dbo.GetWeekNumber(@date, 0) -- 2016, Week 01
```

Answer (score 5):

This is by design.   According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

> ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for
>   weeks. Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday occurs.
>   For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) ran from Monday 29 December 2003
>   to Sunday, 4 January 2004.

So `ISOWK` is always based on Thursday, and is not affected by `DATEFIRST`.

To get the results you want, just use `WEEK` instead of `ISOWK`.

UPDATE:  Also from MSDN:

> January 1 of any year defines the starting number for the week
>   datepart, for example: DATEPART (wk, 'Jan 1, xxxx') = 1, where xxxx is
>   any year.

The only way to get Week #1 to be Jan 3-9 is to use math.  Subtract one from the `DATEPART(wk...)` value, and if the result is 0, make it 53 (or simply use `DATEADD` on your date to subtract a week).   There is no simpler way, as by design, the first week of any year will be the week that contains Jan 1.

Comment: I've also tried `WEEK`, it works correct with `DATEFIRST` but it not what I need, for example, week number for `Jan 1` will be `1`, but I need following numbering (as I wrote above):   Jan 1,2 -> Week 53, Jan 3...9  -> Week 1, Jan 10...16 -> Week 2

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I've found that it can be done well just by adding a day to the date - you can see function and example in the update to my answer.