# How to solve ISO_WEEK partitioning issues for transactions when bridging over two different years

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

I would like to compare records from my table between different years but through the same `ISO_WEEK`.

**Situation:**

My issue is that `ISO_WEEK` sometimes briges between two different years so I can't split correctly the week number from the year. In 2019 for example, `ISO_WEEK` 1 ranges from Dec 31st 2018 to Jan 6th 2019. The query that follows groups them correctly except for one issue where the partition will group by `YEAR` then `ISO_WEEK`, hence excluding Dec 31st for the `ISO_WEEK` 1. How can I fix this for this specific date but all future dates as well?

**My query:**

```
CREATE TABLE [table]
    ([id] varchar(50), [transaction_date] Datetime)

INSERT INTO [table]
VALUES
    (123, '2018-01-01 05:30:00'),
    (456, '2018-12-31 08:30:00'),
    (456, '2019-01-01 06:30:00'),
    (789, '2019-01-02 11:30:00')

SELECT 
     CAST(t.transaction_date AS Date)
    ,id
    ,DATEPART(YEAR, t.transaction_date)
    ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, t.transaction_date)
    ,ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, transaction_date), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, transaction_date), id ORDER BY transaction_date) AS week_count
FROM [table] AS t
```

So if I want to `count` the `ISO_WEEK` 1 of 2019 , it will exclude the value of Dec 31st 2018 because of my partitioning. So how can I modifiy my query so that its included?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure either.   Does this help?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/36340252/1507566

Comment: The *canonical* way to handle date and reporting period issues, especially when week numbers are involved, is to use a Calendar table. You'll only have to join with the Calendar table to get whatever reporting period identifier you want to use. Without it, you'll have to include the week and *year* numbering logic in the query itself

Comment: @SeanLange Modifed my question to add fiddle data to better explain my issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But I added the year and week number in the query. I extracted the those two parts for that purpose. unless i don't get what you're suggesting

Comment: The first element you partition by is the year of transaction_date. So it will be in a different group for row_number. Seems like maybe you should just remove year from the partition? But still totally clear what you expect as output.

Comment: I believe the problem is to use ISO_WEEK from the start. This value will most of the time include different years. I agree with Pan to use a calendar table. Generate one with a decent amount of future years and update manually (one-time) all the values you need. Then simply join. You can add a column that reads "My_ISO_Week" and set your logic there.

Comment: @SeanLange I want my output to show transactions grouped by ISO_WEEK of each year as the reporting will compare Weeks from different years. If I remove year in my partition, ISO_WEEK 1 will include all ISO_WEEK 1 (i.e. from every year) hence inflating numbers.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks but no. My issue is inversely related.

Comment: @EzLo If I use WEEK instead I will have the same issue. Week 53 for 2019 include only 3 days. As for your calendar suggestion, I'm unsure as to how I could make this work?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg I see now, please try to use this "ISO YEAR" and beware that some years have 53 weeks and most 52. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926271/sql-get-iso-year-for-iso-week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is -- alas -- no iso_year date part.  You can calculate it with an expression like this:

```
select year(dateadd(week, 1 - datepart(iso_week, transaction_date), transaction_date))
```

What this does is go back to the beginning of the year and then adds one week.  According to the ISO definition of the year, this will always be in the reference year.

EDIT:

For your query, I would do:

```
SELECT CAST(t.transaction_date AS Date), id, v.td_iso_year, v.td_iso_week,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, td.iso_year ORDER BY transaction_date) AS week_count
FROM [table] t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (YEAR(DATEADD(WEEK, 1 - DATEPART(iso_week, t.transaction_date), t.transaction_date)),
              DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, t.transaction_date) 
             )
     ) v(td_iso_year, td_iso_week);
```

Comment: I don't think you can use ISO_WEEK this way as it's not a built-in function.

Comment: How would I add this in my partition If I would like to count the first transactions of Ids per ISO_WEEK?    
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, t.transaction_date), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, t.transaction_date), count(*) FROM (query) group by ...